# Reuse a window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I have a dialog that works just fine the first time it is invoked. However the second time I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.'
```

To save construction I am using the same Window for every dialog call. It looks like

```
    var result = PreferencesView.ShowDialog();
```

I could over come this by doing something like

```
var result = new PreferencesView().ShowDialog();
```

But I would like to use just one `Window`. Also although I have simplified it here, in real-life constructing the view involves resolving many dependencies (logging, localization, preferences, etc.). I have read solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568233/wpf-cannot-reuse-window-after-it-has-been-closed). But adding OnClosing prevents the error but seems to keep the window visible after the second time.

Comment: Have you tried using show and setting the owner of the window and then calling Hide when closing window?

Answer (score -1):

i haven't tried it but, it should be possible if you use `Form.Hide()` instead of `Form.Close()`.

Greetings,

AW

Comment: That's winforms approach, winforms <> WPF!