# How to open WPF window multiple times in PowerShell script

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, powershell

I have imported the Xaml file into the PowerShell script and opened the window with some text boxes and a button.

On the button click I would like to close that window run some script and then open another window, but I need to be able to do this over and over an infinite number of times until told to stop.

I can open up a new window by naming it window1, but it doesnt open properly and I need to open an "infinite" number of times inside a while loop

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationFramework") | Out-Null

function Import-Xaml {
    [xml]$xaml = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Test\WpfWindow1.xaml"
    $manager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xaml.NameTable
    $manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    $xamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
    [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
}

$window = Import-Xaml
$window1 = Import-Xaml
$Button = $window.FindName("Button")

$Button.Add_Click({  
    $window.Close()   
})

$window.ShowDialog()

#Run Code

$window1.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568233/wpf-cannot-reuse-window-after-it-has-been-closed) (and my experience), WPF `Window`s cannot be shown again once closed. You have two options:

1. Keep the same `Window` instance but change the `Visibility` to `Hidden` instead of closing it (as suggested in the answer above). You might need to reset the `Window` in between uses (e.g. clear text boxes, etc.).
2. Create a new instance of the `Window` every time you need to show it.

Either way, you'll need some kind of loop if you want a potentially 'infinite' number of cycles.

If you go with option 2, I'd suggest only reading the XAML from the file once and keeping it in memory, rather than re-reading the file each time you want to create a new `Window` instance.